# Keyboard and mouse not working after sleep, laptop stuck in tablet mode

Tags: keyboard, suspend, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

This error is difficult to reproduce and doesn't happen 100% of the time, but I have dell inspiron 2 in 1 laptop running ubuntu 22.04. When I close my laptop and put it in sleep mode, and re-open it, often times the touchpad and keyboard are unresponsive and not working. I can still click the screen and pull up the virtual keyboard like it is in tablet mode, but the physical keyboard and touchpad don't work. If I plug in a mouse it will work. Here is a dmesg of me closing my laptop and then opening it and plugging in a mouse if this helps. If permanently disabling tablet mode would help, I would be happy to do that as I don't ever use the touchscreen capabilities, except when I'm forced to.

```
[  580.436916] audit: type=1420 audit(1668554395.531:129): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[  580.508312] ACPI Error: Thread 1349182976 cannot release Mutex [PATM] acquired by thread 1397856640 (20210730/exmutex-378)

[  580.508326] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]

[  580.508328] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]

[  580.508331] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20210730/psparse-529)
[  580.861690] wlp1s0: deauthenticating from 08:62:66:8d:dc:c4 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[  581.393127] intel-vbtn INT33D6:00: Registering Intel Virtual Switches input-dev after receiving a switch event
[  581.393194] input: Intel Virtual Switches as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/INT33D6:00/input/input14
[  581.406650] dell_wmi: Unknown key with type 0x0000 and code 0xe070 pressed
[  581.463422] PM: suspend entry (deep)
[  581.647332] Filesystems sync: 0.183 seconds
[  581.770920] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
[  581.775696] OOM killer disabled.
[  581.775698] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
[  581.777194] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
[  581.805065] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  581.998812] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
[  582.944776] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[  582.985468] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
[  582.990887] ACPI: EC: event blocked
[  582.990888] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
[  582.990888] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
[  582.990923] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  582.992313] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
[  582.994228] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
[  582.996067] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
[  583.000201] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
[  583.000258] ACPI: EC: EC started
[  583.000258] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
[  583.000958] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
[  583.001000] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[  583.001000] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
[  583.003336] CPU1 is up
[  583.003366] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x1
[  583.004309] CPU2 is up
[  583.004338] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x3
[  583.005185] CPU3 is up
[  583.006900] ACPI: PM: Waking up from system sleep state S3
[  583.344666] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[  583.383383] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[  583.385560] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Starting disk
[  583.386461] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[  583.386469] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:102:DDI B/PHY B] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[  583.386475] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:111:DDI C/PHY C] is disabled/in DSI mode with an ungated DDI clock, gate it
[  583.657251] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  583.699427] ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
[  583.703325] ata2: SATA link up 6.0 Gbps (SStatus 133 SControl 300)
[  583.773825] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  583.773829] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  583.773832] ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  583.774943] ata2.00: ACPI cmd ef/10:06:00:00:00:00 (SET FEATURES) succeeded
[  583.774946] ata2.00: ACPI cmd f5/00:00:00:00:00:00 (SECURITY FREEZE LOCK) filtered out
[  583.774948] ata2.00: ACPI cmd b1/c1:00:00:00:00:00 (DEVICE CONFIGURATION OVERLAY) filtered out
[  583.775372] ata2.00: configured for UDMA/133
[  583.775381] ahci 0000:00:17.0: port does not support device sleep
[  583.933308] usb 1-8: reset high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  583.938134] ish-hid {33AECD58-B679-4E54-9BD9-A04D34F0C226}: [hid-ish]: enum_devices_done OK, num_hid_devices=4
[  584.209267] usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  584.485305] usb 1-7: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  584.636306] mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
[  584.636700] OOM killer enabled.
[  584.636701] Restarting tasks ... done.
[  584.709278] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[  584.782244] PM: suspend exit
[  584.810632] usb 1-3: new low-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  584.959866] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0461, idProduct=4d65, bcdDevice= 2.00
[  584.959871] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  584.959872] usb 1-3: Product: USB Optical Mouse
[  584.963265] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:0461:4D65.0007/input/input31
[  584.963495] hid-generic 0003:0461:4D65.0007: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[  585.058826] Bluetooth: hci0: Legacy ROM 2.5 revision 1.0 build 3 week 17 2014
[  585.492024] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.8.10-fw-1.10.3.11.e.bseq
[  585.568696] audit: type=1107 audit(1668627838.564:130): pid=1358 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=? msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_signal"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/login1" interface="org.freedesktop.login1.Manager" member="PrepareForSleep" name=":1.4" mask="receive" pid=3305 label="snap.firefox.firefox" peer_pid=1419 peer_label="unconfined"
                exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=106 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
[  585.568703] audit: type=1420 audit(1668627838.564:131): subj_apparmor=unconfined
[  585.584869] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  585.668573] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[  585.669989] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  585.782818] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[  585.800867] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel BT fw patch 0x32 completed & activated
[  586.593023] hid-sensor-hub 001F:8087:0AC2.0004: timeout waiting for response from ISHTP device
[  586.593065] hid-sensor-hub 001F:8087:0AC2.0003: timeout waiting for response from ISHTP device
[  587.436803] audit: type=1400 audit(1668627840.432:132): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=5105 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
[  587.474488] audit: type=1400 audit(1668627840.472:133): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=5108 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
[  589.168589] wlp1s0: authenticate with 08:62:66:8d:dc:c4
[  589.172628] wlp1s0: send auth to 08:62:66:8d:dc:c4 (try 1/3)
[  589.174156] wlp1s0: authenticated
[  589.176996] wlp1s0: associate with 08:62:66:8d:dc:c4 (try 1/3)
[  589.178082] wlp1s0: RX AssocResp from 08:62:66:8d:dc:c4 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=2)
[  589.179528] wlp1s0: associated
[  589.225364] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp1s0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: I also have this problem, also sporadically, since upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. In my case it's a Dell Latitude. I can use keyboard to enter password at lock screen then kb doesn't work. I was using virtual terminal to restart lightdm. Also was able to recover session using VNC.